# MVC DropDownList: convert List to SelectListItem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, selectlistitem

I have a Controller

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {         
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Users"] = DataFill.GetUsers();
            return View();
        }
    }
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    @Html.DropDownList("Numbers",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["UserList"])
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Model:

```
public class User
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
}
```

And method, that fills list:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetUsers()
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, DbConnection))
    {
        DbConnection.Open();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {

            while (reader.Read())
                UserList.Add(new User {Login = reader.GetString(0), DisplayName = reader.GetString(1)});
        }
    }

    return UserList.ToList();
}
```

But in Visual Studio i get an error:
"Cannot convert expression type User to return type SelectListItem". So how can i convert list that i get from database to SelectListItem type?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to convert your `List` to `SelectListItem`:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> GetUsers() 
{
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, DbConnection)) 
    {
        DbConnection.Open();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) 
        {
            while (reader.Read()) 
            {
                items.Add(new SelectListItem { 
                Text = reader.GetString(0), 
                Value = reader.GetString(1)
                });
            }
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

Comment: I downvoted because you didn't explain why this works or what was fixed to make it work